# Ошибка в Intelli Idea

Tags: java

Закачал обновление для Intellij Idea. Теперь при запуске программы выдает ошибку:
Error:java: invalid source release: 1.9. Что бы это могло быть?

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Project -> Project SDK и Project language level выставляешь нужный ( не 1.9)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov. Благодарю Вас за отзыв. Но там в окошке "Project SDK", есть  <1.8 (java version "1.8.0_65")> и нет SDK. Вместо этого красным шрифтом написано: "No sdk".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878045/errorjava-invalid-source-release-8-in-intellij-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> File -> Project Structure -> Project.

В комбобоксе `Project SDK` выбираете нужную SDK ( если ее нет, тыкаете new и выбираете путь до sdk'шки).

В комбобоксе `Project language level` ставите 8 ( ну или какую джаву требует sdk)